# How do I replace all occurrences of '+' with '.5' in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, replace, substring

I have a dataframe below:

```
data = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Lower': ['+', '2', '2+', '3'],
        'Upper': ['2','3+','4+','5']}

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The expected output should be:

```
data = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Lower': ['.5', '2', '2.5', '3'],
        'Upper': ['2','3.5','4.5','5']}
```

I have tried using the code below but it only replaces + and not 2+, 3+, 4+

> df.replace('+','.5', regex=False)
> I also tried using str.replace but the rest of the values become NaN:
> df['Lower'].str.replace('+', '.5')

Answer (score 0):

you can override the value by looping, but it's not the fastest solution

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Lower': ['+', '2', '2+', '3'],
        'Upper': ['2','3+','4+','5']}

lower = []
upper = []

newdata = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Lower': lower,
        'Upper': upper}

for i in data['Lower']:
    if "+" in i:
        lower.append(i.replace("+", ".5"))
    else:
        lower.append(i)
        
for j in data['Upper']:
    if "+" in j:
        upper.append(j.replace("+", ".5"))
    else:
        upper.append(j)

df= pd.DataFrame(newdata)
print(df)
```